# checking for undefined properties

Tags: javascript, function, undefined

I'd like to get an error message when I misspell a variable name or an object property. Strict mode helps with local variables but what if I read a property?
e.g.

```
var vector = {x: 2, y: 3}
var length = Math.sqrt(vector.x*vector.c + vector.y*vector.y)
```

length will be `NaN`. I don't want to get difficult to find bugs in my code just because of a typo. What's the best way to deal with that? I could add a get function to the prototype of Object and then write e.g. `vector.get("x")` instead of `vector.x`. But I want the undefined checks to be done only in the debugging phase and automatically removed in the finished code.

Comment: Not typoing would be a good start :p Kidding, everyone makes typos. However, I don't think it's worth completely rewriting how JavaScript works just to catch them more easily.

Comment: try asserts start here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6693405/assertive-programming-with-javascript), so you can write methods like get() and use asserts inside them

Comment: Why don't you use typeof function. Check against undefined.

Comment: `try{...}catch(err){...}`??

Comment: I don't want to manually add a typeof check everytime I read a property. Isn't there some browser plugin that can help me? For setting properties there is Object.seal which in combination with "use strict" gives me an error if I accidentially try to change a non existing property, but there is no corresponding functionality for getting undefined properties.

Comment: What you seek is called [unit testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_testing). In this case, you would test that you get a valid (i.e. correct or expected) value for `length` for all possible values of `x` and `y`. It's impossible to prevent coding errors and still have a usefully functioning environment.